# Enable table column sort using Angular

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create a sort a basic table using Angular.

To setup the table I use:

```
<table id="tableSortExample" mdbTable class="z-depth-1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th (click)="sort('One')">One</th>
    <th (click)="sort('Two')">Two</th>
    <th (click)="sort('Three')">Three</th>
    <th (click)="sort('Four')">Four</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of elements; let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{el.id}}</th>
    <td>{{el.first}}</td>
    <td>{{el.last}}</td>
    <td>{{el.handle}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and then define in the component:

```
  sort(colName) {
    console.log('sort clicked : ' + colName);
    this.elements.sort((a, b) => a[colName] > b[colName] ? 1 : a[colName] < b[colName] ? -1 : 0)
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
      this.elements.push({
        id: i,
        first: 'test',
        last: 'Name ' + i,
        handle: 'Handle ' + i
      });
    }
  }
```

On opening the page that contains the HTML the table is rendered :

[image]

But clicking the column headers does not apply the sort.

The function sort is fired on click as can see messages printed to the log:

```
console.log('sort clicked : ' + colName);
```

I'm attempting to work from a previously answered question but it seems I've missed a step or not understood something.

How to enable sort of the columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in the `elements` array are: `id`, `first`, `last`, and `handle`

Replace the arguments in the `sort` functions called.

```
<th (click)="sort('id')">One</th>
<th (click)="sort('first')">Two</th>
<th (click)="sort('last')">Three</th>
<th (click)="sort('handle')">Four</th>
```